# csv files error in R

Tags: r, csv

When trying to read a local csv file im getting the error

> Error in xts(dat, order.by = as.Date(rownames(dat), "%m/%d/%Y")) : 
>     'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'

im trying out the example from https://rpubs.com/mohammadshadan/288218 which is the following:

```
tmp_file <- "test.csv"

# Create dat by reading tmp_file
dat <- read.csv(tmp_file,header=FALSE)

# Convert dat into xts
xts(dat, order.by = as.Date(rownames(dat), "%m/%d/%Y"))

# Read tmp_file using read.zoo
dat_zoo <- read.zoo(tmp_file, index.column = 0, sep = ",", format = "%m/%d/%Y")

# Convert dat_zoo to xts
dat_xts <- as.xts(dat_zoo)
```

the thing is when i try to read the file like in the example which is reading the file from the server this works somehow but not when i try with  a csv file locally even if its the same info as the file in the web.

i have tried creating the csv file with Notepad,Notepad++ and Excel with no luck.
Any idea what im missing?, i have also tried using read.table instead of csv with the same results...

File can be found at: https://ufile.io/zfqje

if header=TRUE i get the following error:

> Warning messages: 1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep =
>   sep, quote = quote,  :   incomplete final line found by
>   readTableHeader on 'test.csv' 
>   2: In read(file, ...) :   incomplete
>   final line found by readTableHeader on 'test.csv'

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example so we can troubleshoot?

Comment: uploaded it to: https://ufile.io/zfqje

Comment: Can you use dput() on it instead and share a few lines of it here, in your question?

Comment: No error for me. The result comes as: `dat_xts
           a b
2015-01-02 1 3
2015-02-03 2 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `header=FALSE` argument in `read.csv`.

`read.csv` will choose the first column as the row names if there is a header and the first row contains one fewer field than the number of columns. When `header = FALSE`, it doesn't create the row names.

Here is an example of the problem:

```
dat <- read.csv(text = "a,b
1/02/2015,1,3
2/03/2015,2,4", header = F)

as.Date(rownames(dat), "%m/%d/%Y")
#> [1] NA NA NA
```

By removing `header = F`, the problem is fixed:

```
dat <- read.csv(text = "a,b
1/02/2015,1,3
2/03/2015,2,4")

as.Date(rownames(dat), "%m/%d/%Y")
#> [1] "2015-01-02" "2015-02-03"
```

Comment: sorry i forgot i left it in FALSE but even if i try with TRUE i get another error, ill add it to the original problem

Comment: @Makenshi, Your CSV is just missing a newline at the end.

Comment: Wow, the simplest thing of all was causing the error, Thanks! it works now